# Is this a valid Python string formatting technique for localization?

Tags: python, localization, gettext

Can someone tell me if this is the correct approach for localizing my Python strings? It works great but I cannot find anywhere whether or not this is exactly how I should be doing it. Many thanks!!!

In my Python script, I have taken following string formatting approach:

```
print(_('{0} does not exist').format(file_name))
```

My message.pot file contains this:

```
#: some_file.py:65
#, python-format
msgid "{0} does not exist"
msgstr ""
```

My translated file (messages_fr.po) is like this:

```
#: some_file.py:65
#, python-format
msgid "{0} does not exist"
msgstr "{0} n'existe pas"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly how L10N should be performed on simple strings. Note that the filename of the message catalog will depend on how exactly I18N was performed.